# lighttpd - защита паролем

Tags: unix, веб-сервер

Установил одну софтину, она автоматически подняла веб-сервер lighttpd (который вижу в первый раз) для веб-морды. От вебморды отказываться не хочется, но она полностью доступна без пароля и светит в веб.
Как можно сделать авторизацию по паролю по принципу апача - поправить конфиг по типу .htaccess для защиты конкретной папки.

Comment: Вы уверены, что светит? Пробовали с другого компьютера с другим интернет-провайдером заходить?

Comment: Абсолютно уверен. У компьютера выделенный ip, и забив в его в любом браузере открывается эта самая веб-морда. Закрывать в файерволе 80 порт тоже не вариант. Менять lighttpd на апач лениво (но возможно и придется).

Comment: `.htaccess` — это исключительно «apache-вское» «изобретение». если конфигурационный файл таки имеется — проще будет [ограничить слушаемые интерфейсы](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Server_bindDetails). но если очень хочется повозиться, так [пожалуйста](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/HowToBasicAuth).

Comment: Настройки lighttpd находятся в файле /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf, который может подтягивать соседние .conf файлы. Скорее всего, Вам потребуется подключить модуль mod_auth. Обратите внимание на его настройки https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/lighttpd_doc/authentification.html и пошаговый пример использования https://wiki.autosys.tk/linux_faq/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-lighttpd-how-to-use-authentication-with-lighttpd-htpasswd?

Comment: Учтите, что все настройки могут иметь ограничения по включению в различные версии сервера 1.4, поэтому нужно сверяться с официальным руководством https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_Configuration

Comment: Здесь можно ознакомиться со всеми настройками модуля mod_auth https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Mod_auth